# printing part of file

Tags: file, parsing, unix

Is there a magic unix command for printing part of a file?  I have a file that has several millions of lines and I would like to skip first million or so lines and print the next million lines of the file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: print to a printer that is already installed to your system and working? Or print onto your screen, or "print" to a file? : -)

Answer (score 1):

To extract data, `sed` is your friend.

Assuming a 1-off task that you can enter to your cmd-line:

```
sed -n '200000,300000p' file | enscript
```

"number comma (,) number" is one form of a range cmd in sed. This one starts at line 2,000,000 and ***p***rints until you get to 3,000,000.

If you want the output to go to your screen remove the `| enscript`

`enscript` is a utility that manages the process of sending data to Postscript compatible printers. My Linux distro doesn't have that, so its not necessarily a std utility. Hopefully you know what command you need to redirect to to get output printed to paper.

If you want to "print" to another file, use

```
sed -n '200000,300000p' file > smallerFile
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `awk` as it is a little easier and more flexible than `sed`:

```
awk 'FNR>12 && FNR<23' file
```

where `FNR` is the record number. So the above prints lines above 12 and below 23.

And you can make it more specific like this:

```
awk 'FNR<100 || FNR >990' file
```

which prints lines if the record number is less than 100 or over 990. Or, lines over 100 and lines containing "fred"

```
awk 'FNR >100 || /fred/' file
```